# Is mkfs cause OS corruption and why?

Tags: filesystem

I am working on a VM running a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with one 34 GB partition.

First, I use cfdisk to resize the partition to 24gb then create a partion that is 10gb.

Then I try and make a filesystem on the new partition.
doing this causes the filesystem to become read only

```
pj@ubuntu:/$ mkfs -v -t ext4 /dev/sda2
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Could not open /dev/sda2: Permission denied
pj@ubuntu:/$ sudo !!
sudo mkfs -v -t ext4 /dev/sda2
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
fs_types for mke2fs.conf resolution: 'ext4'
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
655360 inodes, 2621184 blocks
131059 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=2151677952
80 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Filesystem UUID: af601173-c7e3-4386-9eab-f9926454509a
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (16384 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done 

pj@ubuntu:/$ touch /file2
touch: cannot touch '/file2': Read-only file system
```

When I reboot the computer I am in grub rescue.
Why is this happening?

Comment: [Edit] your post to include the output of `lsblk` and `mount | grep "/dev/"`

Comment: Did you shrink the filesystem (resize2fs) before shrinking its partition?  If not, the filesystem is damaged, maybe files lost. Since you've reformatted the new partition, assume any files lost are permanently gone.  run fsck (from install media) on the original partition to fix the errors.